# Run JUnit tests in isolated temporary working directory?

Tags: java, junit, temporary-directory

I have a Maven project with some JUnit-based tests. My code creates files in the current working directory. I want to test that these files are generated and then compare their result.

To isolate the tests, I want to run my tests/application in a temporary directory that is removed after the application terminates.

I have found out about `TemporaryFolder` and `@Rule` in JUnit. However, apparently, I cannot change the current working repository in the `@Before` test by some limitation in Java in general.

Can I somehow configure this through Maven, that the current working directory is set to a freshly create temporary directory that is removed after the test terminates?